# Yii2 use form tags

Tags: forms, yii2

When I submit my form i got some errors,
This is my form script which contains posted fields.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action'=>'userpermission/create',
    ]); ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('admin/userpermission/create')?>">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'idPermission')->checkboxList(ArrayHelper::map(Permission::find()->all(),"idPermission", "libelle", [
                    'onclick' => "$(this).val( $('input:checkbox:checked').val());",
                    'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
                    return "<label class='ckbox ckbox-primary col-md-4'><input type='checkbox' {$checked} name='{$name}' value='{$value}' tabindex='3'>{$label}</label>";

                    }
                ])) ?>
            </li><br>  
       </ul>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Valider' : 'Create' ,['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-primary','value'=>'Create', 'name'=>'submit']) ?>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

and my create function looks like but i got the error undefined variable model!

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Userpermission();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            print_r(Yii::$app->request->post());
            exit;
            return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
    }
```

Comment: have u used Userpermission with proper namespace?

Answer (score 2):

1st off, you dont need that **`<form>`** tag.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action'=>'userpermission/create',
    ]); ?>
```

creates and initializes the form for you with corresponding client-validations.

the possible issue is due to unclosed `</form>` which anyways is unnecessary. 
suggesting to remove the `<form>` tag entirely. and try again and if any issue please let me know the error.
also bring the `print_r(Yii::$app->request->post());` before `if` condition.
enable error reporting in your function

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

please give the filename to code block. it would be easier to understand that way.

Comment: firstly thank you for the response, so i got the following error "PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException

Undefined variable: model " To let you know i am working on the index page in my user model and i call the userpermission model create function